# Minimum and Maximum .

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

In a book it has been written that

"Taking the minimum and maximum of each term we see that on $[0,1]$ the function, $y=x^3-7x^2+1$" , is bounded below by c$=0-7+1=-6$ and above by d$=1+0+1=2$.

I am not understanding how they calculate the c and d ?

Comment: Are u allowed to use derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They simply splitted calculation of $\min x^3-7x^2+1$ into $\min x^3$, $\min -7x^2$, $\min 1$.

As $x \in [0,1]$:

- $\min x^3=0$ (because $x^3>0$ for $x>0$ and $0^3=0$)
- $\min -7x^2=-7$, because it is a monotically decreasing function on $[0,1]$ with minimum at $x=1$, which is easy to see, as any $0\leq x<1$, $-7x^2>-7$
- $\min 1=1$, as it is a constant function

Of course thic minimum is not actually achievable (as it requires $x$ to be both 0 and 1), but it gives the lower bound of the whole equation. Similarly with the upper bound.

Comment: Could you please explain what will be the lower bound when the function is $\sqrt(1-x^2)$ ?

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[0,1]$ is a monoticaly decreasing function, which achieves minimum in $x=1$. If you take $x=1$, then $\sqrt{1-x^2}=0$, but as $\sqrt{a}\geq 0, \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, you know that $\min \sqrt{1-x^2} = 0$, for $x \in [0,1]$. You should check out **wolfram alpha** for such simple function analysis: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%281-x%5E2%29

Answer (score 2):

The key here is:

> Taking the minimum and maximum of each term ...

Here, the terms of the given function are $x^3$, $-7x^2$ and $1$.

The minimum of the term $x^3$ in the interval $[0,1]$ is $0$ and max is $1$.

Similarly for other terms as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're gone while I asked you the comment. If you are allowed to use the derivatives, then you could get the answers better. Our function is $f(x)=x^3-7x^2+1$ and you know that it is differentiable **at least** $2$ times. So we have $$f'(x)=3x^2-14x$$ Since $f'(x)$ is a polynomial so the critical points can be achieved by setting $f'=0$. This gives us $$x=0,~~x=14/3$$ We have  then: $$x_1=0,~~f''(0)=-14\longrightarrow f(0)=+1 ~~\text{relative max}\\ x_2=14/3,~~f''(14/3)=+14\longrightarrow f(14/3)\approx-49 ~~\text{relative min}$$ But you are given an interval $[0,1]$. Considering that $x_2\notin I$ so we compute $f(1)$ and then probe the finial results:
 $$f(0)=0,~~f(1)=-5$$ So on $I$: $$-5\le f(x)\le +1$$

[image]

Comment: $+1 \ddot\smile$